Find the fundamental group of the punctured solid bitorus.
I would appreciate any hints on how to determine the fundamental group of the punctured solid bitorus, that is, the solid genus $2$ compact connected orientable two dimensional surface with a point removed.
In the case of the solid torus with a point removed, it is easy to see, by deformation retract of the point to a disk removed, and contraction of that disk to make it into the wedge of a sphere and a circle, that its fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$ (and for $k$ points removed, it's the wedge of a circle and $k$ spheres, so it remains $\mathbb{Z}$.)
But I couldn't manage to apply the same idea for the solid bitorus with a point removed.

Try applying SVK

Which opens sets should I take? In the case of the boundary bitorus, it is easy to do that using the fundamental polygon, but in the solid case, I can't find an easy way.

Do you remove the point from the boundary or from the interior?

Wedge of sphere and circle has fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ not $\mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}$. The solid torus with $k$-interior points removed should still have fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}$ not $\ast_{k+1} \mathbb{Z}$?

I think there should be a homotopy equivalence of the solid genus $g$ with interior point removed with the wegde $S^2 \vee \bigvee_g S^1 $, so it has fundamental group $\ast_{k} \mathbb{Z}$...

I tried applied the same argument to the torus, considering the point was removed from the inside: to expand it into a disk, contracting the disk and its boundary in order to get a wedge of two solid tori. Hence the fundamental group of the solid bitorus minus a point is $\mathbb{Z}\ast \mathbb{Z}.$ Seems it doesn't matter how many points you remove as well, since $\mathbb{S}^2$ is simply connected.

First, if you have a connected topological manifold with boundary and $x_0,y_0 \in \text{int}(M)$ are two arbitrary interior points, then $\pi_1(M\setminus\{x_0\}) \cong \pi_1(M\setminus\{y_0\})$. So, it does not matter which point you remove.
Now, a solid genus $g$ surface is up to homeomorphism a solid $2$-sphere $D^3$ with handles $H_i \cong D^2 \times [0,1]$ for $i = 0, \dots, g$ attached to its boundary at $2g$ disjoint $2$-disks $D^2\cong D_j \subseteq \partial D^3$ for $j=0,\dots ,2g$.
So it is
$$\Sigma_g = D^3 \cup_{\coprod_{j=1}^{2g} D_i} \coprod_{i=1}^{g} H_i.$$
Remove now the center $m$ of $D^3$ in $\Sigma_g$ and get
$$\Sigma_g \setminus\{m\} = (D^3\setminus \{0\}) \cup_{\coprod_{j=1}^{2g} D_i} \coprod_{i=1}^{g} H_i.$$
Then contract the handles to lines and deform $D^3\setminus \{0\}$ to $S^2$. Then $\Sigma_g\setminus\{m\}$ deformation retracts to
$$S^2\cup_{\{x_1,\dots,x_{2g}\}}\coprod_{i=1}^{g} [0,1] \simeq S^2\vee \bigvee_{i=1}^{g} S^1.$$
Therefore
$$\pi_1(\Sigma_g \setminus \{m\}) \cong \pi_1(S^2\vee \bigvee_{i=1}^{g} S^1) \cong \ast_{i=1}^g \mathbb{Z}$$
since $S^2$ is simply connected and $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ by Seifert-van-Kampen theorem.
This also works if you remove finitely many points $\{x_1,\dots,x_r\}$ from the interior. Then as above w.l.o.g. they are all in the interior of the middle solid $2$-sphere $D^3$ and $D^3\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_r\}$ is simply connected since $D^3\setminus\{x_1,\dots,x_r\} \simeq \bigvee_{i=1}^r S^2$ and also in this case
$$\pi_1(\Sigma_g \setminus \{m\}) \cong \pi_1(\bigvee_{k=1}^r S^2\vee \bigvee_{i=1}^{g} S^1) \cong \ast_{i=1}^g \mathbb{Z}.$$
If you remove (arbitrary many) boundary points $X \subseteq \partial M$ then $M$ itself is a deformation retract of $M \setminus X$, i.e. $M \simeq M \setminus X$, (because the boundary has a collar neighborhood) and thus they are the same from homotopy theoretic view point. In particular, $\pi_1(M \setminus X) \cong \pi_1(M)$.
So, in this case it is $\Sigma_g\setminus \{X\} \simeq \Sigma_g \simeq \bigvee_{i=1}^{g} S^1$ and therefore it has the same fundamental group
$$\pi_1(\Sigma_g\setminus \{X\}) \cong \pi_1(\bigvee_{i=1}^{g} S^1) \cong \ast_{i=1}^g \mathbb{Z}.$$
Now, take $g = 2$ and get $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$.
